# Is there a way to integrate TinyMCE and EasyAdmin 3.x Bundle in Symfony 5.1

Tags: tinymce, symfony5, easyadmin

I'm trying to integrate stfalcon/TinymceBundle with EasyAdmin 3. I tried to create custom form template which works on Index and Details page, but not on the Edit/Create pages. I'm interested in knowing if someone realized that WYSIWYG in easyadmin3.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add to your DashboardController this:

```
public function configureCrud(): Crud
{
    return Crud::new()
        // add your form theme here
        ->addFormTheme('@BundleName/Form/wysiwyg_widget.html.twig')
    ;
}
```